# Renew ticket on keypress or mouse event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, mouseevent, keypress

I am using C# on a website to create session by using FormsAuthenticationTicket.

The ticket code for the FormsAuthenticationTicket is as following

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, 
                                                                 model.UserName,
                                                                 DateTime.Now,
                                                                 DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                                                                 false,
                                                                 admin.Role);
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket) {   Expires = ticket.Expiration });
```

Every part of the website inherits Site.Master, so I wanted to add something among these lines into the Site.Master

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('mousemove mouseclick keydown mousewheel', idle);
});

function idle(e) {
    if (window.idleTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(window.idleTimeout);
    }
    <%= FormsIdentity identity = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;  %>
    <%= FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(identity.Ticket); %>
    window.idleTimeout = setTimeout(userIdle, 900000);
}
function userIdle() {
    //either do stuff here or trigger the "idle" event
    $(window).trigger('idle');
}
```

This does not work. It can not use the FormsIdentity becuase I can not do "using System.Web.Security;" here.

Is there any similar logic I can use to keep refreshing the Ticket on events like keypress and mouse events?

FYI: The ticket does not expire if I go to other parts of the website, so that is not the problem. Only when people use like 40min on completing a form then trying to submit it and lose all progress. Sure I could just increase the timeout but this is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send an AJAX request to the server in order to refresh the cookie:

```
function idle(e) {
    if (window.idleTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(window.idleTimeout);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= Url.Action("RenewCookie") %>',
        type: 'POST'
    });
    window.idleTimeout = setTimeout(userIdle, 900000);
}
```

then on your server you will have a controller action that will perform the necessary steps. But beware, hamerring your server with AJAX requests on every single keystroke or mousewheel could be devastating.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions that would stress the server less then? Would it be possible to do it client side?

Comment: No, the only possible way to renew a forms authentication cookie is by sending a request to the server. So if you want to perform less requests you could maintain a list of events on the client and at regular intervals check whether there are events in this list and send only a single AJAX request.